# Sharing 'Exclude from Import and Completion' settings for entire project in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

Here are my current local `Exclude from Import and Completion` settings in IntelliJ at `Editor -> General -> Auto Import`:

[image: Exclude from Import and Completion]

I'd like to share them among all developers in the project using file committed to `.idea` to avoid manual steps to setup environment.

However, when I search `.idea` for these exclusions I cannot find anything. Changes in the list do not change `.idea` in any way. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose "Project" in the "Scope" column for the entries you wish to share. After that, .idea/codeInsightSettings.xml should appear with these settings which you can share.